# Do we need to take any action on answers that mismatch current tag of questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, answers

I just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37820743) with C# solution while the question is in C++, but I believe it is just caused by poor tagging idea by OP before (according to current existing comments). Is there any action need to take for 'outdated' answers?

I think the C# answer is not helpful for C++ programmers, but flagging it to delete seems not very ethical, because it is caused by the wrong tag of OP at the beginning, what should we do?

Comment: Why would that not be ethical? Them's the breaks; the question showed signs of lack of clarity and confusion of composition from the start, so anyone who risked answering it has to accept the chance of having their answer go awry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe the user should have posted an answer for a couple different reasons.  First, the question is unclear in that the title states C++ but it was tagged C#.  One of those is wrong but without input from the OP we cannot know which. Secondly, the question is a duplicate in both languages, so it should not have been answered but instead flagged/close-voted as a duplicate.

Now, since it is tagged as C++, the C# answer is not useful.  Non-useful answers are prime targets for down-votes and delete votes.  So had this not been a bad question, but merely someone providing a C# answer to a C++ question, then that answer should be deleted.  A comment to the user first giving them the chance to remedy the situation would also be nice.

In this specific case, though, I say we can just delete the question and wipe it all out.  The question itself is not needed, as it has already been asked and answered.  I have already cast a delete vote on that question, and if 2 other users do too, it will wipe out the entire post.